# Can i get any help to build a questionnaire/mcqs application with multiple scoring categories in django

Tags: python, django, web

I am a begginner in django and I have been given a project to build a questionnaire or an Mcq's web application with categorical scoring system... Did anyone can provide me the link or help related to this type of application...
Thank You

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMTVAIVrdtM

**But i really recommand you to learn the django basics:**

Django Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/

A very good tutorial on YT:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmljXZIypDc

Comment: Thank You!!! but I've watched this tutorial but it's not the same as client wants. It is like i've to create aquestionnaire of python, js and php and it'll show me the total scoring of all these subjects separately